# Connect two lamps to the same ceiling socket, controlled by two three-way switches

Tags: wiring, lighting, lamp

Apologies if this is a stupid question, but my google fu is failing me.

I have a ceiling socket for a lamp. I want to use it to power two lamps, controlled by the same two three-way switches. How do I achieve that? I thought there'd be some sort of standard 'splitter' box I can connect to the endpoint and then connect the individual lamps to that, but I cannot find anything. Thanks in advance

**EDIT2**: completely forgot that the light is actually controlled by two switches, not one

**EDIT**: here's the socket, standard EU I believe, brown wire, light blue wire, and earth
[image: the ceiling socket]

Comment: We're going to need a picture of your ceiling socket.

Comment: Oops, good point, uploaded an image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking at things from the lamp's perspective.  *From that perspective, multi-way switching is irrelevant*.

On the lugs are the switched-hot and neutral that you need to provide to the other lamp.  Just carry it from there to the other lamp, and you're done.

Comment: OK, so it's simply a matter of sticking two new wires in the same connector holes currently going to the existing lamp, and connecting them to the new lamp? I see, I thought it'd be harder :-)

Answer (score 0):

Going from fixture to fixture I would get 3 lever locks. 3 contacts on each one. Connect the wires in the same way the wires top and bottom on the right connect in 2 of the openings  of 1 lever lock . The wires top and bottom left in another lever lock and then the ground in the 3rd now you can connect the ground to the existing fixture and a new cable that runs to the new fixture in the corresponding openings on the 3 (I can’t make out the colors) . 
With the connections made inside the fixture this would meet the way it is currently connected. If the fixture doesn’t have a enclosure for the wiring a box would be needed on this side of the pond.

Comment: Thanks. I find it hard to follow - I get that a lever lock is [one of these](https://www.superbrightleds.com/moreinfo/wire-connectors/28-12-ga-lever-lock-quick-connect-terminal-blocks/1372/) but I struggle to undersatand how to connect them all up together

Answer (score 0):

@harper-reinstate-monica's mention of "lugs" (yes, I'm *that* clueless) took me to this page which explains the whole thing in simple terms accessible to a total beginner like myself. Leaving it here should anyone get here via a google search

https://www.flameport.com/electric/lighting_circuits/lighting_overview.cs4